# Creating forms for Multiple Nested Resources in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been following Ryan Bates' tutorial on nested forms [Railscast 196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast)

The form for the new action shows the nested attributes for quizzes but does not show nested attributes for the key. I am guessing this is because quizzes have a has_many relationship where key has a has_one relationship... But I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated!

This is my model:

```
class Repository < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :quizzes, :dependent => :destroy
   has_one :key, :dependent => :destroy

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :key, :quizzes
end
```

This is my controller:

```
def new
  @repository = Repository.new
  3.times { @repository.quizzes.build }
  @repository.key = Key.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @repository }
  end
end
```

This is my view:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :wp_uid %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :wp_uid %>
<% f.fields_for :quizzes do |quiz_fields| %>
  <p>
    <%= quiz_fields.label :name, "Name" %><br />
    <%= quiz_fields.text_field :name %>
  </p>
<% end %>
<% f.fields_for :key do |key_fields| %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= key_fields.label :value, "Value" %><br />
  <%= key_fields.text_field :value %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
  <%= key_fields.label :expiry, "Expiry" %><br />
  <%= key_fields.date_select :expiry %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try modifying your fields_for blocks to use <%= %>

Try changing to:

```
<%= f.fields_for :key do |key_fields| %>
```

The railscast could have been made before the change in Rails 3 to use <%= %> instead of <%%>.

Ryan has a nested_form gem that you may find useful for this as well.  I haven't tried using it yet, but plan to next time I start a new project.

https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Answer (score 0):

Try building the key object as

@reposity.build_key

From the rails docmentation
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Unsaved+objects+and+associations

If you wish to assign an object to a has_one association without saving it, use the build_association method. The object being replaced will still be saved to update its foreign key.

Comment: I did this too, but it did not fix my issue. Thanks though :)